# Sprite or UIImage should be used in 2d unity for Information display board?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a table containing information that I have drawn by myself, I want to display it in my project, the content is unchanged but I don't know whether to create an object or whether a UIImage contains it.

I looked over and saw that UIImage seems to be an Image object, so it will be heavier than an object?

I want to know which object and UIImage is better for displaying an image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what youre trying to ask is if you should use a world object with a sprite renderer? or a UI object with an Image component?

These serve two completely different purposes. First off, is this content going to be constantly displayed to the user on screen? If so then you will want to use a canvas with a UI image element as you can set ancor points so that the content is properly resized for different screen ratios. You will also want to turn off the raycast target option underneath the image settings for better performance (that is if its is not a button or something the user can interact with)

Now if the content isnt going to be constantly displayed then by all meams throw it on a world object with a sprite renderer, keep in mind that this wont be resized or follow the camera (if the camera is moving). Use this [link](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UIMultiResolution.html) if you need to get a better understanding on how to properly set up a UI element to handle different aspect ratios

Comment: Images on 2D objects. I just want to know if there is any difference between the Object content image and the UI image and which one is better for displaying the content. Thanks for replay.